# How to print xtable without hlines

Tags: r, latex, xtable

assume I have a simply xtable, made as follows:

```
library(xtable)
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,3,3))
x <- xtable(x)
```

How can I print this table with only the columns (i.e. '&'s), but not anything around? I do not want hlines explicitly.

Using:

```
print(x,
only.contents=T)
```

returns `\hline` before and after the table. I'd be also happy with a workaround, even though I hope it is possible somehow within xtable to set this up as intended. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `hline.after` to `NULL`; see below:

```r
library(xtable)
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,3,3))
```

```
print(xtable(x),
      only.contents=T)

#> % latex table generated in R 3.6.0 by xtable 1.8-4 package
#> % Wed Sep 18 11:54:58 2019
#>  & V1 & V2 & V3 \\ 
#>   \hline
#> 1 &   1 &   4 &   7 \\ 
#>   2 &   2 &   5 &   8 \\ 
#>   3 &   3 &   6 &   9 \\ 
#>    \hline
```

```
print(xtable(x),
      hline.after = NULL,
      only.contents=T)

#> % latex table generated in R 3.6.0 by xtable 1.8-4 package
#> % Wed Sep 18 11:54:58 2019
#>  & V1 & V2 & V3 \\ 
#>  1 &   1 &   4 &   7 \\ 
#>   2 &   2 &   5 &   8 \\ 
#>   3 &   3 &   6 &   9 \\ 
#>
```

You can read more in `?print.xtable`.